# Array to Map: no suitable method found for Collectors.toMap

Tags: java, dictionary, java-stream, collect

I want to convert array into Map using Java 8 streams:

```
String[] arr = {"two", "times", "two", "is", "four"};
Arrays.stream(arr).collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s, 1, Integer::sum);
```

The `s -> s` part is marked as error

> no instance(s) of type variable(s) T, U exists so that Integer conforms to Function

Comment: the second argument to `toMap` is a function so change `1` to `u -> 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the `1` is the error. The value `1` cannot serve as the `valueMapper`, whose type should be `Function<? super T, ? extends U>`.

In your example the value mapper should be a function that accepts an element of your `Stream` (a `String`) and returns an `Integer`. The lambda expression `s -> 1` will do.

The following works:

```
String[] arr = {"two", "times", "two", "is", "four"};
Map<String,Integer> map = Arrays.stream(arr).collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s, s -> 1, Integer::sum));
System.out.println (map);
```

Output:

```
{times=1, four=1, is=1, two=2}
```

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted, as it's correct. Though `Collectors.counting()` would probably be the better alternative